# Rails require path is correct but still cannot load such file error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, filesystems, include

Im trying to include a file in my view with:

```
  = require Rails.root + 'app/assets/js_manual/counters/members.js'
```

cat /full/path/to/app/assets/js_manual/counters/members.js
goes fine i see the contents of the file, just rails won't load it in

Is there anything I can do on this i suspect file/folder permissions but i cannot change my whole disk rights to get rails to load a single file in.

Answer (score 3):

What you most likely want to do is

```
= javascript_include_tag '/js_manual/counters/members.js'
```

What you're doing now is using the `ruby` language's `require` primitive, which does not do what you want.

Comment: Yes I know i can use the JS include but I wanted to include JS files outside the asset pipeline so i could have some files stored in js_manual that will not end up in the asset pipeline the require code i used seems to not work because of disk permissions wich i cannot change that would be unwanted workaround.